# Checking server status

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check the status on multiple servers at the same time but when I load the form the app is just freezing without any error. This is what im using to check server status. Any idea?

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

try
{
    tcpClient.Connect("ip address here", port);
    Status1.Text = "Online";
    Status1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Status1.Text = "Offline";
    Status1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

try
{
    tcpClient.Connect("ip address here", port);
    Status2.Text = "Online";
    Status2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Status2.Text = "Offline";
    Status2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: `Connect` is synchronous call, it blocks the UI until get a response. Try to use `ConnectAsync` or check a connection in a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code snippet, this will not block the UI thread and keep the form responsive.

```
    static async Task CheckConnection()
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("ip address here", port);
            Status1.Text = "Online";
            Status1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        catch(AggregateException a)
        {
            Status1.Text = "Offline";
            Status1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Status1.Text = "Offline";
            Status1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

if you are new to this programming model, check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)